# Does New Relic support ASP.NET Core's ILogger?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, newrelic

I'm new to New Relic. I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.2 (targeting .NET Core 2.2) hosted on an Azure App Service. I've followed the instructions [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/azure-installation/install-net-agent-azure-web-apps)  and it seems to be working, as I can see requests being logged.

Is ASP.NET Core's `ILogger` interface supported in New Relic? i.e. can I do `logger.LogDebug("Blah")` in my app and have it logged somewhere in New Relic so that I can trace requests?

Comment: Serilog has a NewRelic sink I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Serilog has [Serilog.Sinks.NewRelic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.NewRelic/) Nuget Package. If you use serilog you can connect your application with NewRelic via *Serilog.Sinks.NewRelic* sink.

Serilog can be configured and used with `ILogger`, and the configuration can be done via `ILoggerFactory`

See [this link](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging) for Serilog Configuration

As a side note, It is also fairly easy with Serilog to write your own Sink.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where in New Relic I would see logs such as the "Blah" one in my question? I'm new to New Relic so don't know if that's even supported.

Comment: Sorry, unfortuantely I dont have experience on that.